# how to make android app to run in background, service example?

Tags: android

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
   import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.widget.TextView;

      public class TelephonyDemo extends Activity {
       TextView textOut;
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
      PhoneStateListener listener;

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Get the UI
    textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOut);

    // Get the telephony manager
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // Create a new PhoneStateListener
    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    String stateString = "N/A";
    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
      stateString = "Idle";
      break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
      stateString = "Off Hook";
      break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
      stateString = "Ringing";
      break;
    }
    textOut.append(String.format("\nonCallStateChanged: %s", stateString));
  }
};

// Register the listener with the telephony manager
telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

  }
  startService();

   }
```

how to make my application run in background? to read phone state whole time?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

no need to have "Service" in this current question.

You may use BroadcastReceiver component to be able to receive broadcasted intent PHONE_STATE_CHANGED all the time even if your Activiy (Visible/interactive part of your application) is hidden/removed.
this way your app will react each time PHONE STATE actually changing. no need to have a "Listener" mechanism.

see more on BroadCastReceiver at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html